# HTML Form to upload FTP Folder

Tags: php, html, forms, ftp

I'm trying to create an idea that I thought of.
I thought to create a page where you write in an HTML form your FTP server, username, password, folder and choose an option from a dropdown menu and then itll upload certain files to that folder,
Currently I'm having some issues [ maybe cuz I never got to finish learning PHP, I just can't sit infront of a PC and study something , idk why ]
I do know some basis and I read in PHP Documentary.

My current code: [ HTML ]

```
<form name="ftpupload" action="" method="post">
Server: <input type="text" name="server" ><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
Folder: <input type="folder" name="folder"><br>
System: <select name ="sys"><br>
<option value="check">Check</option>
<option value="2ndcheck">2nd Check</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$ftpServer = $_POST['server'];
$ftpUser = $_POST['user'];
$ftpPass = $_POST['pass'];
$ftpFolder = $_POST['folder'];
$ftpSys = $_POST['sys'];
if($ftpSys == 'check') { $fileName = "test.txt"; $remoteFile ="2ndindex.txt"; }
elseif($ftpSys =='2ndcheck') { $fileName = "2ndtest.txt"; $remoteFile ="2ndindex.txt"; }
//FTP Connection
$conn = ftp_connect($ftpServer) ; 
//
if (@ftp_login($conn, $ftpUser, $ftpPass)) {
    //echo "Connected as $ftpUser@$ftpServer\n";
?>
<div class="working">
Connected as <? echo "$ftpUser@$ftpServer" ?> 
</div>
<?
ftp_put($conn, $ftpFolder, $fileName, FTP_ASCII);
    } else {
?>
<div class="working">
Could not connect as <? echo "$ftpUser@$ftpServer" ?> 
</div>
<?
}
```

Because of the limited ftp_put function, I don't know how to put the fileName and ftpFolder together, so itll put it there with that name,
after this test will work I want to get it to upload all the files and folders that are in a certain folder, is that possible?
EDIT: Oh and another small thing : How can I get the PHP acting only after the form was submitted?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't require anything special. When you log in with the user, you are assigned a certain directory that you start in. on Shared hosting packages on a linux environment.

This is generally:

```
/home/username/
```

then from there, you can choose whatever directory, like:

```
'/public_html/'.$ftpFolder.'/.'$fileName;
```

If you only want the PHP to execute after the form has been submit, then you need to perform a conditional. You can check as many or as little posted variables as you want.

```
if(isset($_POST['server'])):
    //your logic.
endif;
```

If you need to know what directory you're set into by default, you can use

```
ftp_pwd();
```

which returns the present working directory for the FTP connection.